# slow down the slidingdrawer close animation

Tags: android, animation, slidingdrawer, sliding

I am using a SlidingDrawer in my app. My problem is that when i use`drawer.animateClose()` the drawer is closing to fast. how can I slow it down?
Thanks!

Comment: Get a slower device! (sorry, couldn't resist...)

Comment: ha ha...  now, how can it be done?